# Can I use EP 80W/90 oil instead of EP90 oil in a Belle MiniMix 150 gearbox?

Tags: cement, oil

I have a Belle MiniMix 150 110V Electric Cement Mixer  the documentation says to use a EP90 oil, but these days it seems that most outlets only sells EP80/90 oil.

What is the difference and doe sit matter?

Answer (score 2):

I just got this response from Belle.

> Yes you would be able to use EP80/90.   We recommend to change the oil
>   every 6/12 months but this is dependant on use.